# Differentiating the line types in plotting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I'm having trouble choosing the line types for the figure below. It looks like some kind of intricate figure. Do you have any suggestions for determining the line types?

My script below is:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(months,bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'bv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'b>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'b<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbb_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'ks-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'b^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax1.plot(months,bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'cv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax1.plot(months,bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'c>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax1.plot(months,bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'c<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax1.plot(months,bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'kp-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12)
ax1.plot(months,bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'c^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'rv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'r>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'r<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'k*-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12)
ax2.plot(months,bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'r^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'gv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'g>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'g<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
ax2.plot(months,(bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'kP-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12)
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'g^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize)
plt.title("Precipitation Perturbation")
#plt.xlabel("Month")
ax1.set_ylabel('Hydrologic States (mm)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Hydrologic Fluxes (mm/day)')
ax2.legend(["P(70%)","P(80%)","P(90%)","P(100%)","P(110%)",\
            "ET(70%)","ET(80%)","ET(90%)","ET(100%)","ET(110%)","Q(70%)","Q(80%)","Q(90%)","Q(100%)","Q(110%)"],loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.045, 0.5))
    ax1.legend(["SWE(70%)","SWE(80%)","SWE(90%)","SWE(100%)","SWE(110%)"],loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.06, 0.5))
#plt.legend(["P","ET","Q"])
# Show the major grid lines with dark grey lines
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-',alpha=0.2)
# Show the minor grid lines with very faint and almost transparent grey lines
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image: linetypes]

Comment: "*choosing the line types for the figure below*" - what do you mean? can you provide more details about your objective?

Comment: I want to make the lines as readable and distinguishable as possible so I want to change the linetypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `linestyle` parameter provided with the [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) function.

The following example will use the standard built-in named formats, but you can craft your own [custom](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) linestyles.

```
ax2.plot(months,bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'bv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'b>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'b<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-')
ax2.plot(months,bbb_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'ks-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12,linestyle='-')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly['OUT_PREC']['mean'],'b^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-')
ax1.plot(months,bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'cv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='--')
ax1.plot(months,bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'c>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='--')
ax1.plot(months,bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'c<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='--')
ax1.plot(months,bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'kp-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12,linestyle='--')
ax1.plot(months,bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_SWE']['mean'],'c^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='--')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'rv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-.')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'r>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-.')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'r<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-.')
ax2.plot(months,bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'k*-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12,linestyle='-.')
ax2.plot(months,bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_EVAP']['mean'],'r^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle='-.')
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec070_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'gv-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle=':')
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec080_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'g>-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle=':')
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec090_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'g<-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle=':')
ax2.plot(months,(bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbb_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'kP-',alpha=0.5,markersize=12,linestyle=':')
ax2.plot(months,(bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_BASEFLOW']['mean']+bbprec110_vicoutput_monthly[' OUT_RUNOFF']['mean']),'g^-',alpha=0.5,markersize=marksize,linestyle=':')
```